# Chopping audio files with ffmpeg get None duration python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a long list of audio files, and some of them are longer than an hour. I am using Python 3.6, Jupyter notebook by connecting to a remote machine and using TinyTag library to get a duration of audio. Ffmpeg version is 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

My code below goes over the files and if a file is longer than an hour, it splits the file into one-hour long pieces, and a leftover piece less than an hour, and copies the pieces as fname_0, fname_1,fname_2, etc. Before chopped, each file is .m4a but during chopping, they are converted to a .wav file. However, after this chopping process, when reading the duration of pieces, I realized that all the pieces have 'None' duration. Something must be wrong in the command line but I can`t see what that is. Thanks in advance.

```
# fpaths is the list of filepaths
for i in range(0,len(fpaths)):
    fpath=fpaths[i]
    fname=os.path.basename(fpath)
    fname0=os.path.splitext(fname)[0] #name without extension
    tag = TinyTag.get(fname)
    if tag.duration > 3600:
        cmd2 = "ffmpeg -i %s -f segment -segment_time 3600 -c copy %s" %(fpath, fname0) + "_%d.wav"
        os.system(cmd2)
        os.remove(fpath)
```

Comment: Might help if you include some additional details in your question, such as: your operating system; your distro (as appropriate; e.g., CentOS or Ubuntu); your OS version; and how you installed ffmpeg. From what I can tell, this is largely related to the behavior of the `ffmpeg` command-line utility, which could vary between operating systems, installation packages, etc.

Comment: thank you, SpencerD, I just edited my question.

Comment: To verify, _"most"_ of the pieces are effected, but *not* _"all"_? Not trying to pick apart the issue without warrant; I just want to make sure I am clearly understanding the problem. If the answer to the former is yes (_most_ but not _all_), then follow-on question: is the issue at the segment-level or does it tend to affect the whole file? (I.e., do some of the segments for a  file come out correctly, while other segments of the same file come out broken? Or does the issue tend to present with either all segments working or none work?) Either way, sounds like it is probably a codec issue.

Comment: it is my bad i checked, ' all' the pieces were None duration. I will edit it in my questions, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When I change to the extension from .wav to .m4a in the cmd2 command line, it works. Writing here just in case if someone has the same problem.

Comment: Remove the `-c copy` to get a regular WAV.